# Identification of a real subspace H of codimension 2 (of $\Bbb{C}^3$) to $\lbrace z_1+2z_2+3z_3+2\varepsilon R(z_1)=0\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

let R be The real part . I use $ 2\varepsilon R(z_1)$, Where $\varepsilon>0$, to get a small real perturbation of $\lbrace z_1+2z_2+3z_3=0\rbrace$ such that it become a real subspace of $\Bbb{C}^3$. I want to know if any real subspace H of $\Bbb{C}^3$ of real codimension 2 can be writen H= $\lbrace z_1+2z_2+3z_3+2\varepsilon R(z_1)=0\rbrace$ (maybe by some tronsformation).

Comment: To be clear, you mean by *complex-linear* transformation?

Comment: yes I mean that or in general if there is any method to show it.